# REGEX: remove left of string until special character

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following value `ora:hashedPassword` I want a regex to remove the whole left string until the `:` so is left with `hashedPassword`

I am doing the following currently but only accepts one value to replace, in my current scenario, the array value could contain multiple string patterns `(ora:value1, org:value2,pfog1r0:value2)`

```js
var schemaArr = ['ora:hashedPassword', 'org:DISTRIB_VALUES_OTH', 'org:categoryTrackingLogStats', 'org:champsPersoAutres', 'org:champsPersoBoutique', 'org:deliveryDOLogStats', 'org:ebNotif', 'org:familleTypologie', 'org:filActuNewBox', 'org:lovDevice', 'org:newBoxNotif', 'org:potentielFibre', 'org:tempsSaison', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_DO', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_OFFER_RANGE', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_TARGET', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_TARGET_DO', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_TGT_OFRG', 'pfog1r0:OPERATION_PRT_WAVES', 'pfog1r0:OPERATION_TMK_SUPPLIER'];

var arrayLength = schemaArr.length;

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  console.log(schemaArr[i], "auto_" + schemaArr[i].replace("org:", '') + "_seq")
}
```

Comment: What about `schemaArr[i].split(':')[1]`? Also, the example does not use any regex?

Comment: guess this works also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regex to replace all characters leading up to the colon could be as simple as `/.*?:/`

```js
var schemaArr = ['ora:hashedPassword', 'org:DISTRIB_VALUES_OTH', 'org:categoryTrackingLogStats', 'org:champsPersoAutres', 'org:champsPersoBoutique', 'org:deliveryDOLogStats', 'org:ebNotif', 'org:familleTypologie', 'org:filActuNewBox', 'org:lovDevice', 'org:newBoxNotif', 'org:potentielFibre', 'org:tempsSaison', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_DO', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_OFFER_RANGE', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_TARGET', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_TARGET_DO', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_TGT_OFRG', 'pfog1r0:OPERATION_PRT_WAVES', 'pfog1r0:OPERATION_TMK_SUPPLIER'];

var arrayLength = schemaArr.length;

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  console.log(schemaArr[i], "auto_" + schemaArr[i].replace(/.*?:/, '') + "_seq")
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `g` flag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use match and `(?<=:)` `lookbehind` approach, to find the text after `:`

```js
var schemaArr = ['ora:hashedPassword', 'org:DISTRIB_VALUES_OTH', 'org:categoryTrackingLogStats', 'org:champsPersoAutres', 'org:champsPersoBoutique', 'org:deliveryDOLogStats', 'org:ebNotif', 'org:familleTypologie', 'org:filActuNewBox', 'org:lovDevice', 'org:newBoxNotif', 'org:potentielFibre', 'org:tempsSaison', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_DO', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_OFFER_RANGE', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_TARGET', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_TARGET_DO', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_TGT_OFRG', 'pfog1r0:OPERATION_PRT_WAVES', 'pfog1r0:OPERATION_TMK_SUPPLIER'];

const result = schemaArr.map(i => i.match(/(?<=:)\w+/)[0])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

So the regex is very short: `/.+:/`.

- `.+` - one or more characters
- `:` followed by a colon

There are couple of ways to iterate over these strings depending on whether you want to mutate the existing array, or create a new array of changed elements.

1. Mutate the existing array

```js
const schemaArr = ['ora:hashedPassword', 'org:DISTRIB_VALUES_OTH', 'org:categoryTrackingLogStats', 'org:champsPersoAutres', 'org:champsPersoBoutique', 'org:deliveryDOLogStats', 'org:ebNotif', 'org:familleTypologie', 'org:filActuNewBox', 'org:lovDevice', 'org:newBoxNotif', 'org:potentielFibre', 'org:tempsSaison', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_DO', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_OFFER_RANGE', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_TARGET', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_TARGET_DO', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_TGT_OFRG', 'pfog1r0:OPERATION_PRT_WAVES', 'pfog1r0:OPERATION_TMK_SUPPLIER'];

for (let i = 0; i < schemaArr.length; i++) {
  schemaArr[i] = schemaArr[i].replace(/.+:/, '');
}

console.log(schemaArr);
```

2. Create a *new updated* array using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over each element and returning a changed element to the output array.

```js
const schemaArr = ['ora:hashedPassword', 'org:DISTRIB_VALUES_OTH', 'org:categoryTrackingLogStats', 'org:champsPersoAutres', 'org:champsPersoBoutique', 'org:deliveryDOLogStats', 'org:ebNotif', 'org:familleTypologie', 'org:filActuNewBox', 'org:lovDevice', 'org:newBoxNotif', 'org:potentielFibre', 'org:tempsSaison', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_DO', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_OFFER_RANGE', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_TARGET', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_TARGET_DO', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_TGT_OFRG', 'pfog1r0:OPERATION_PRT_WAVES', 'pfog1r0:OPERATION_TMK_SUPPLIER'];

const updated = schemaArr.map(el => {
  return el.replace(/.+:/, '');
});

console.log(updated);
```

An alternative method (as mentioned in the comments) might be to just [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string on the colon to create an array, and then return the second element

```js
const schemaArr = ['ora:hashedPassword', 'org:DISTRIB_VALUES_OTH', 'org:categoryTrackingLogStats', 'org:champsPersoAutres', 'org:champsPersoBoutique', 'org:deliveryDOLogStats', 'org:ebNotif', 'org:familleTypologie', 'org:filActuNewBox', 'org:lovDevice', 'org:newBoxNotif', 'org:potentielFibre', 'org:tempsSaison', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_DO', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_OFFER_RANGE', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_TARGET', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_TARGET_DO', 'pfog1r0:BRIEF_DELIVERY_TGT_OFRG', 'pfog1r0:OPERATION_PRT_WAVES', 'pfog1r0:OPERATION_TMK_SUPPLIER'];

const updated = schemaArr.map(el => {
  return el.split(':')[1];
});

console.log(updated);
```